# SVN Error:An error occurred while contacting the repository at “xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx”. The server may be unreachable or the URL may be incorrect

Tags: svn

CornerStone added a new repository, add succeed! Interface display error message:An error occurred while contacting the repository at “xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx”.  The server may be unreachable or the URL may be incorrect.

Comment: read [ask] before writing a question

Answer (score 1):

You can try : clear your keychain's Cornerstone password , or try Cornerstone v3.0.1